# Uploaded a txt file with PHP - changing the contents before the file is uploaded?

Tags: php

I'm uploading a txt file to a server, but I want to format it with a little RegEx first. How would I have it sent to the PHP script, change its contents, then upload it?

I get its filename from `$_FILES["userinput"]["name"]` and then save the contents of it with `file_get_contents()` and then edit it. But now how do I move this edited string to the server instead of the original, unedited file.

I was thinking of creating a new .txt file and filling it with the contents of the string then uploading that, but that doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a way to just modify the file that's trying to be uploaded?

Comment: That's not the "official" way to do file uploads. Check out [this document and example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for an "official" way.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but PHP runs on the server, not the client. So in order to "edit" a file BEFORE it's uploaded, this would have to be done on the client. your PHP page can't do that. You CAN upload a file, then modify it and save/move/delete it. Again, though -- you can't edit a file on the client from server side code.

Comment: @mrunion You can edit an uploaded file just fine with server-side code.

Comment: @Passerby If you're going to be doing operations on the file, I don't see the problem with reading it into memory first and then writing it later.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware @Waleed. Based on this quote `How would I have it sent to the PHP script, change its contents, then upload it?` he wants to change it BEFORE he uploads it. you can't do that with server side PHP unless it's uploaded first.

Comment: @mrunion He *says* he wants to change it before it is uploaded, but I don't think that's what he *wants*. "Upload" is a term which was misused in this question.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Technically the files has been "written" to server (to a temp folder/path). There is nothing wrong with modifying before putting it to an indented place, but still he should use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` and `move_uploaded_file` instead of what he post in his question.

Comment: Thanks guys, what I mean is that (and please feel free to correct any poor understanding) when the user clicks submit, I know it's uploaded to a temporary location, and if nothing is done it will be removed. Before I put it in a permanent location I'd like to change the .txt file a little bit. Is this possible? As in modifying it before the `move_uploaded_files()` function? Like maybe overwrite the file in the temp directory? Or use that function with a file I create? What's the best way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before a file is uploaded in PHP it is saved as a temp file, That file contains the contents of the file and when you upload the file it basically uploads your temp file. So all you would need to do is to change the contents of the file with the name `$_FILES['userinput']['tmp_name'];` and when you upload it'll grab your modified temp file and upload it.
Editing the file would be easy, Here is an example of how you would do this:

```
$filevalue = file_get_contents($_FILES['userinput']['tmp_name']);
$newfilevalue = PUT YOUR CODE HERE!
file_put_contents($_FILES['userinput']['tmp_name'], $newfilevalue);
```

NOTE: Please click the green tick or 1 point up button if I've helped!

Comment: How would I go about modifying the contents of that file, though?

Comment: I just added how you would go about doing this :)